# Facebook getLoginUrl and next parameter doesn't work properly

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

My Code:

```
$url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email','next'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/APPID/'));
echo "<script> top.location=\"".$url."\"; </script>";
```

I need to redirect the user to apps URL of my application when authetication is successfull but it always redirect to my redirect_uri page.

how can i fix it?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to change this URL to redirect you app where you want after authentication.

[image: You have to change this URL to redirect you app where you want after authentication.]

**OR You can Do this**

First of all, you don't have to edit PHP SDK, below is the sample for authenticating the user and then redirecting to your landing page,

Make sure you replace:

YOUR-APP-ID-HERE with Your facebook application id,

YOUR-APP-API-SECRET-HERE with Your facebook application secret key

YOUR-REDIRECT-URL-HERE with Your landing page URL

```
<?php

    // Requires Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.1: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/
    require ('facebook.php');

    define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID',"YOUR-APP-ID-HERE");
    define('FACEBOOK_SECRET',"YOUR-APP-API-SECRET-HERE");
    define('REDIRECT_URI',"YOUR-REDIRECT-URL-HERE");
    $user = null;

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser(); // Get the UID of the connected user, or 0 if the Facebook user is not connected.

    if($user == 0) {
        // If the user is not connected to your application, redirect the user to authentication page
        /**
         * Get a Login URL for use with redirects. By default, full page redirect is
         * assumed. If you are using the generated URL with a window.open() call in
         * JavaScript, you can pass in display=popup as part of the $params.
         * 
         * The parameters:
         * - redirect_uri: the url to go to after a successful login
         * - scope: comma separated list of requested extended perms
         */

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI));

        echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");

    } else {
        // if the user is already connected, then redirect them to landing page or show some content
        echo ("<script> window.location.href='".REDIRECT_URI."'</script>");
    }

?>
```

If you want to get extended permissions, then simply add another "scope" parameter to the login url, ex:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' => REDIRECT_URI,'scope' => 'comma-separated-list-of-requested-extended-perms'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the redirect uri in the app settings page.

Comment: if the link has been set in the apps page then as Mike says change the 'next' value to where you want it to point to.

Comment: i point it to 'http://apps.facebook.com/APPID/' but it always redirect to my canvas url, i mean it.